# retrieve contacts without Google Account?

Tags: contacts, external-sd, google, sim-card, ios

I had an Iphone with a sim card. Then I bought a new sim card with a new number to put in my Iphone because I was out of the country. Now I've lost the Iphone with the new sim card. I bought an Android phone and inserted my previous card. How can I retrieve my contacts? They're not on Icloud and not on Google.

Would it work if I put my sim card in another Iphone? If not, what other ways are there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your old SIM card to iPhone for a while, then follow
**settings > contacts > import from SIM**

Answer (score 0):

If you had internet on your iPhone (the one you lost) then your contacts should be on icloud, it syncs by default. iPhone doesn't save to sim card by default. It will keep it on the phone itself and back up to cloud.

But you're saying that you're sure that the info is *not* on cloud, and if that's the case, then there's no way you can retrieve your contacts because they're only present on your phone, which you've lost.